# Left align a single text line within a block of math equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, text, flalign

How can one left align a single text line ("and", in the following example) within a block of math. equations? `\shortintertext{and}` seems to generate larger interline spacing which is undesirable.

Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools} 

\begin{document} 
    \begin{align*} 
        2x - 5y &=  8, \\
        \text{and} \\
        3x + 9y &=  -12.
    \end{align*}
    
    \begin{align*} 
        2x - 5y &=  8, \\
        \shortintertext{and} \\
        3x + 9y &=  -12.
    \end{align*}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: no `\\ ` after interline text

Comment: Use `\shortintertext{and}` (`mathtools`), with no following `\\ ` as noted by @DavidCarlisle.

Comment: Yes, thank you both.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP's issue was solved in the comments.

Comment: @Mico We already have two answers. So wouldn't it be better to have one more answer with David's comment and a MWE showing this?

Comment: I agree, voting to leave open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\shortintertext{and}` (from `mathtools`), with no following `\\`

Answer (score 1):

The `align` environment opens display math mode and starts it by `\halign` primitive, which controls the alignment. There is a TeX primitive `\noalign{vertical material}` which can be used at the end of each row in `\halign`, i.e. just after `\cr`. The LaTeX macro `\shortintertext` is implemented by `\noalign` primitive. Your example ca be we-written using this primitive like this (note that LaTeX's `\\` is `\cr` in this context):

```
\begin{align*} 
    &2x - 5y =  8, \cr  \noalign{\hbox{and}}
    &3x + 9y =  -12.
\end{align*}
```

If you add another `\cr` just after `\noalign{...}` then next empty row is appended. But you don't want such empty row here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing the alignment point on the left of expressions? It will make all lines to be left-aligned

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools} 

\begin{document} 
    \begin{align*} 
        &2x - 5y =  8, \\
        &\text{and} \\
        &3x + 9y =  -12.
    \end{align*}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The text "and" needs to be justified to the left. The comments above solve it.